# Java Scanner Split ArrayOutOfBounds

Tags: java

I am trying to make program that have a different behavior when the user inputs certain arguments to a String that is received by the program through a Scanner. My problem is the fact that i want to make it as if the user doesn't write the 2nd argument for example, the program should still work.

```
static String ReadString() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        return scan.nextLine();
    }
String command = ReadString();
String words[]=new String[4];
words[0]="empty";
words[1]="empty";
words[2]="empty";
words[3]="empty";
words  = command.split(" ");
```

The problem is that if I am calling for example words[1] after the user has written only one argument to that string, I still get the error ArrayOutOfBounds, although there should be an string with the value "empty".

Example:
 User writes : ababbbbb command1 >>> when I call words[1] it should give me command1

User writes : ababbbbb  >>> when I call words[1] it should give me empty

Comment: I didn't get mentioned error when executed your code

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough with the problem.I've given an example of what I want to do.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because, when you wrote below code that means `words` which is Array of String type is pointing to reference, which is allocated memory to hold 4 string.

```
String words[]=new String[4];
```

Now, below line of code where you are creating Array by spliting them by `" "` has only size 1. Now, `words` variable reference has changed and it can only hold 1 `String`.

```
words  = command.split(" ");
```

You need to make following correction :

```
   String command = ReadString();
   String words[]=new String[4];
   String[] n = command.split(" ");

   for(int i=0; i< 4; i++)
    {
      if((n.length-1)==i)
      {
         words[i]=n[i];
      }
      else
      {
         words[i]="empty";
      }
    }
```

**>>>[Demo](https://ideone.com/Snwf3z)<<<**

Comment: Ok..I've modified the code to  String words[] = command.split(" ");  . Now I can call each string that was splitted from the original one. But now how can I ensure that if the string doesn't have enough arguments to to fill the array  and the words[2] for example doesn't exist, still want to fill that position with something inside. Because I am trying to use if(words[2]==null) words[2]="empty" ;  I still get the out of bounds error.